# Change content of a XAML-element with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my main XAML page there is a `ScrollViewer`. In this `ScrollViewer` I want to display two different XAML pages depending on a boolean variable in my main C# code. To display only one XAML page in the `ScrollViewer` this code is working:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="323" Name="Schieber">
   <local:Scrollanwendung_standard/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

As I said, there is another XAML page named `Scrollanwendung_anwendung`, that I want to display depending on a boolean variable.

In the main C# code I tried the following solution, that does not work:

```
if(x==true)
{
   Schieber.Content=Scrollanwendung_admin
}
else
{
   Schieber.Content=Scrollanwendung_standard
}
```

How can I change the content of the `ScrollViewer` named `Schieber` with the boolean variable?

Comment: I think hiding one page and showing the other one should do the job. (changing the `Visibility` property of the two pages).

Comment: The code equivalent of your XAML would be `Schieber.Content = new Scrollanwendung_standard();`, i.e. you would assign an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put both pages inside the `ScrollViewer` and have one hidden. Then whenever the value would change you would show the other page and hide the first one. Something like this:

SomeWindow.xaml

```xml
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="323" Name="Schieber">
    <Grid>
        <local:Scrollanwendung_standard x:Name="pageOne"/>
        <local:Scrollanwendung_anwendung x:Name="pageTwo" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

SomeWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
if(x==true)
{
    pageOne.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    pageTwo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
else
{
    pageOne.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    pageTwo.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the content of `ScollViewer` should work just fine. I assume, that `Scrollanwendung_admin` and `Scrollanwendung_standard` are types, not instances.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="323" Name="Schieber">
<local:Scrollanwendung_standard/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In XAML the lines above will create *a new instance* of `Scrollanwendung_standard`. However, in your code you assign *types* as content, not *instances*.

```
if (x)
{
   Schieber.Content = new Scrollanwendung_admin();
}
else
{
   Schieber.Content = new Scrollanwendung_standard();
}
```